# descargar un archivo con javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

En una vista `HTML` tengo un href el cual tiene un data_id con un valor 'X' y una clase, cuando yo oprimo en el link hago una ajax validando si ese dato (data_id) realmente existe, lo que intento hacer es que en el done si existe que me descargue el archivo sino ps que no haga nada pero no encuentro la manera de poder descargarlo, no me sirve usar `<a href="download/mi_archivo.jpg" download="mi_archivo.jpg">` dentro del `HTML` ya que busco una manera mas elegante de poder hacerlo con el `JS.`

Este es el codigo con el cual lo intento realizar.

```
$(document).on("click", ".it-file", function()
    { 
        var txitxa = $(this).data("fileinformationstdid");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'downloadfileinformationstdid',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'txitxa' : txitxa}
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            var answer = $.parseJSON(response);
            if(answer <= 0)
            {
                alert("Error","Este archivo no se encuentra en la base de 
                                    datos","error");
            }
            else
            {
                var url="../../download/" + answer[0].formato_filenamestd;    
                window.open(url, 'Download');
            }
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        });
```

Comment: Estoy usando PHP

Comment: *¿No me sirve hacerlo con `<a download>`?*. ¿Se puede saber por qué dices eso? Además, ¿qué quieres decir con *"una manera más elegante"*?

Comment: Si quizas tienes la voluntad de colaborarme te explico, esto es lo que he puesto <a href="download/mi_archivo.jpg" download="mi_archivo.jpg"> no es la forma de la que quisiera manejarlo, y si hablo de elegante es cambiar la metodologia por algo mejor realizado, es ir manejando las cosas a otro nivel y de una manera diferente...si lo has entendido espero haber resolvido tus preguntas para que puedas colaborarme con una solucion.

Comment: tu respuesta es  un poco amplia con el codigo seria un poco mejor..no entendi muy bien. quedo atento.

Comment: @Daniel, es solo un comentario y con el busco saber si estas interesado en una solución que pueda incluir `PHP` (tag no incluido en tu pregunta).

Comment: @Marcos Gallardo Claro que si me interesa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es hacer que el navegador vaya a la url que deseas descargar ... eso lo consigues con la instrucción `location.href` de Javascript, asignandole el valor de la url que quieres descargar.

A continuación un ejemplo:

```js
$(function () {
 function downloadLink(id) {
     var ajaxOptions = {
      url: 'http://httpbin.org/status/' + id
        };
        
        var res = $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
        
        function onAjaxDone(data) {
          
          location.href = 'http://httpbin.org/bytes/1024';
        }
        
        function onAjaxFail() {
         alert('Bad ID');
        }
        
        res
         .done(onAjaxDone)
            .fail(onAjaxFail)
        ;
    }
    
 function onDownloadLinkClick(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var id = $this.data('id');
        downloadLink(id);
    }
    
 $('.download-link').on('click', onDownloadLinkClick);
});
```

```css
.download-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: .5em;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #c00;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" data-id="200" class="download-link">Good ID</a>
<a href="#" data-id="400" class="download-link">Bad ID</a>
```

Suerte y Saludos!

Comment: Hola @JesusGoku tu codigo es exactamente lo que yo necesitaba pero no se que problema tengo que el archivo en ves de descargarse lo que hace es que me lo muestra en una nueva pestaña del navegador

Comment: @Daniel Por lo que comentas se me ocurre que en tu función que maneja el evento **click** en los enlaces debes pasar como argumento el objeto **Event** ... `$(document).on("click", ".it-file", function(e)` y luego sobre el, evitar el comportamiento por defecto invocando `e.preventDefault();`, puedes ver un ejemplo de invocación en mi código. Saludos.

Comment: No hno aun poniendo el event.preventDefault(); me redirige a una nueva pestaña mostrandome el documento,(no me lo descarga) igualmente te agradezco la ayuda depronto me sera util mas adelante, quien sabe. Te Agradezco.

Comment: @Daniel ... tal vez esto te sirva [Forzar descarga de archivos con PHP](https://www.ngeeks.com/forzar-descargas-de-archivos-con-php/) ... Con esto aunque se abra una nueva pestaña, se forzara la descarga del archivo y luego la pestaña se cerrara automaticamente. Espero te sea de utilidad. Saludos.

Comment: Excelente @JesusGoku te agradezco por ese detalle...me sirvio mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Pues yo pienso que el "`<a href="" download=""/>`" esta bien, si quieres dejarlo mas bonito simplemete mete la etiqueta `<a>` dentro de una imagen o texto; sin ningun texto y asi no se verá el enlace pero funcionara de igual forma, si ese es el problema de usar "download", pues realmente no es un problema.

Comment: Hola @Antonio, bienvenido a [es.so]! Gracias por tu aporte. Sin embargo, no entiendo cómo es que estás proponiendo que se descargue un archivo de esta forma. ¿Podrías incluir un ejemplo de código que responda a la pregunta? La idea es sumar respuestas al sitio con la mayor calidad posible. Pensemos en alguien que recién se inicia en esto y se encuentra con este mismo problema, buscando resolver y entender por qué o cómo funcionan las cosas. Quizás un muy breve fragmento de código haría toda la diferencia. Creo que te puede servir realizar el [tour] y leer la información del artículo [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Una forma simple es con una etiqueta

Paso 1 (Opcional para mostrar el archivo)  con una etiqueta input mostramos el archivo que se va a descargar:

```
<input type="file" id="input-file-now" data-plugin="dropify"  data-default- 
file="URL_DOCUMENTO"/>
```

Paso 2: Ponemos una etiqueta a donde le incluimos el url y simplemente damos clic y se nos descarga:

```
<a href="URL_DOCUMENTO" download> Descargar </a>
```

Codigo Completo html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<input type="file" id="input-file-now" data-plugin="dropify"  data- 
default-file="URL_DOCUMENTO"/>
<a href="URL_DOCUMENTO" download> Descargar </a> 

</body>
</html>
```

espero que les sirva